# What to do when the answers complement each other?

Tags: discussion, answers

So, I have asked this [question here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135926/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-ac-of-a-mirror-image-duplicate). It currently has two answers, but none of them is  complete (in my opinion). The first lacks the citation of cover as AC bonus, and the second answer last paragraph is wrong, as people have pointed out.

Following the suggestions of the [answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1141/47052) of this question, I would pick the second answer because I was looking for bonuses beyond increasing DEX. But it would still be an incomplete answer.

So, should I edit one of the answers to make it complete or comment on the answers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Write your own answer

If it's still only hours or even a few days after asking the question, I'd definitely suggest [KorvinStarmast's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8566/35259) about encouraging one of the answerers to update their answer. However, there's only so much control you have over them (this isn't about pestering them, after all), and changing their answer substantially isn't really what edits are for...

So write your own. Reference their answers via links (like I did with KorvinStarmast's answer above) to give credit where you take from their answers, and tie them together with your own wording that makes sense to you; effectively **your answer's purpose is to explain to others why you think these other two answers form a "complete" answer when combined**.

See if there's any criticism against your answer in the next day or so, and if it seems to have been well received, then you can accept your own as the "complete" answer.

Answer (score 8):

### Comment on each answer, explaining what each lacks.

Then let the authors improve their answer, or not.  That is the kind of thing comments are for.

Also, there’s no need to accept either until you feel that the question is well and fully answered.

Comment: Also, there’s no need to accept either.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah, I'll add that. Thx.