# When there are multiple near-identical correct answers, which answer should be accepted?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer

What is the general consensus for accepting an answer when there are multiple, near identical answers posted at the same time?

Not my question, but the question "[Can a Bard use an arcane focus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143898/can-a-bard-use-an-arcane-focus)"
has 2 answers that are near identical (and in my opinion both correct) and were posted within minutes of each other, which I would say are within typing time so aren't copies of each other.

I, of course, upvoted both, but the question asker will end up accepting one or the other. That means one will miss out on being an accepted answer, which people value highly, and which people searching for answers to the same question will see as correct.

So I was just wondering if there is a general best practice on RPG.SE for accepting one answer over another. I have no particular reason for asking; I just thought it was an interesting situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do when there's more than one good answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1140/321).

Comment: This question possibly distinct in that the other question is talking about multiple good answers saying different things - not multiple answers saying the same thing.

Comment: @V2Blast this is only slightly different, and I'm sure the answer is still the same: up to the asker which one is more helpful to them.

Comment: Yeah that covers it. Not sure why I was unable to find that when I was thinking about this. Might have been search terms and the slight difference V2Blast pointed out. Either way I'm satisfied with this result. Thanks.